# Apple TVs keep losing audio output settings

Tags: audio, appletv

I've recently noticed on a few 4k Apple TVs (all on auto update so they are running the latest TVOS) that the sound output options "keep breaking".

What happens is that the Apple TVs stop outputting sound, and you have to go to the menu and reset the audio output settings. Ive seen this happen on Apple TVs that are set the "best audio mode", "5.1" and "2ch".

All the TVs and Apple TVs are set to have CEC off.

Has anyone else seen this happening ?

Any idea how to resolve it ?

Comment: Are you connecting the ATVs to the displays solely through HDMI, or are you using the digital output?

Comment: @IconDaemon solely through the HDMI. But the Apple TVs are in a rack and distributed to multiple TVs through an HDbaseT matrix. This is a pretty standard AV integration setup and dose not seem to cause EDID (Extended Display Identification Data (basically sound and video settings)) issues with any other video sources.

Comment: What HDbaseT device (mfg&model) are you using? Do you intend for *any* ATV to play on *any* monitor in the matrix, or does each ATV have a dedicated monitor? Sounds like a dumb question, but are you using the full capabilities of the ATVs, (streaming video, AirPlay,) or are they used as slide show devices with iPhoto sharing? Where I work, we have ATVs in all locations basically to allow users to display their Mac/iOS screens wirelessly through AirPlay to monitors or projectors and forgo a cabled connection, but we lock down the 'consumer' capabilities. We don't even leave a steal-able remote.

Comment: @IconDaemon its a Pulse 8 - Neo Modular 8x8 4k matrix. The ATVs are mainly used for consuming content (eg. netflix, etc) they may be used for Airplay, but my guess would be relatively infrequently. There are 4x TVs in the install and 4x Apple TVs, although the ATVs run through the matrix, they are not actually matrixed, they are just in the rack to keep the install tidy. There are other devices though that are distributed through the matrix to all 4x TVs and these work fine.